Page is not updated with HotReload message
I have a Blazor Server Side hosted with WebassemblyClient application on .NET 8, which has been around since .NET 5 and has been repeatedly updated. At some point hot relaod stopped working. I would like to tackle the problem now. Hot relaod is running correctly. A corresponding message also appears in the network tab of the browser, the typical hook is displayed in the browser, but the website is not updated. Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Checking Launch Settings

Checking Output Window

Checking Network Tab

Ask ChatGPT

Ask Google

Ask here



My hot reload has been pretty inconsistent between blazor server, WASM and XAF.
Although it's still not working 100%, seems like the auto save extension I was using in VS code was messing with it a bit.
